# get variables through their name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to assign the value of input element to a variable, my form contains say 10 inputs each having unique id and same amount of variables having same name as of the input id's, further I have assigned a function `saveChanges()` to all inputs `onChange` attribute the class goes like this

```
class MainClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var field1 = "";
        var field2 = "";
        var date1 = "";
        var description = "";
        //...
        function saveChanges() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("inputs").onchange = function (event) {
                // tried to use window["variable name"] to access the variables but page broke and goes into repetitive reload
                // need to know that is there any other method to save the changed value to respective variable
                window[event.target.id] = event.target.value;
            }
        }
        function sendDetails() {
            // use the values of the variables and send through rest api
        }
        return (
            <div>
                lable1:
                <input id="field1" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                lable2:
                <input id="field2" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                date1:
                <input id="date1" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                Description:
                <textarea id="discription" className="inputs" onChange={saveChanges }>
                </textarea>
                //...
                <button id="sendDetails" onClick={sendDetails }>
                    Send
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give names to your inputs, and get access to it with `event.target.name`:

```
class MainClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var field1 = "";
        var field2 = "";
        var date1 = "";
        var description = "";
        //...
        function saveChanges(e) {
            this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
        }
        function sendDetails() {
            // use the values of the variables and send through rest api
            console.log(this.state);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                lable1:
                <input id="field1" name="field1" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                lable2:
                <input id="field2" name="field2" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                date1:
                <input id="date1" name="date1" className="inputs" type="text" onChange={saveChanges } /><br />
                Description:
                <textarea id="discription" className="inputs" onChange={saveChanges }>
                </textarea>
                //...
                <button id="sendDetails" onClick={sendDetails }>
                    Send
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: but event.target.id also returns the id value then what's the purpose of using another attribute 'name'

Comment: well the suggestion to set the state is quite helpful as i was considering to set the variables